# Tensorflow supervisor for both training and evaluating operations?

Tags: tensorflow

I've been using tensorflow supervisor (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/supervisor) for loading the model from the saved checkpoints for both training and running a network. But I noticed that the checkpoint files get updated even when running/evaluating the model (timestamps of graph.pbtxt, model.ckpt.data files updated and new events.out created).

This makes me wonder if using a supervisor for running/evaluating the model resets/alters the trained state as well? Is it advisable to use supervisor for anything other than training?

Train -

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=mylogdir)
with sv.managed_session() as sess:
    if not sv.should_stop(): 
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: xtrain, y_: ytrain, keep_prob: 0.5}, session= sess)
```

Run/Evaluate only. We don't want the below to modify the trained state of the model

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=mylogdir)    
with sv.managed_session() as sess:
    for yconv in sess.run(y_conv, feed_dict={x: xtest, keep_prob: 1.0}): 
        #use yconv to predict, evaluate etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is usually saved to a file names 'model.ckpt-NUM'. As long as the evaluation does not update that file (and it shouldn't), then you're safe.

If you are worried about overwriting logging/summaries. You should be careful in choosing the summaries names.

E.g. for evaluation, choose a summary name `'eval/' +metric_name`, and for training `'train/' +metric_name`, for example, see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/eval_image_classifier.py#L162) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/train_image_classifier.py#L320).

EDIT:
You can also choose a different directory ("`logdir`") for storing the evaluations results, as in the of API shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/summary/generation_of_summaries_#FileWriter.__init__)

Comment: Thanks. The evaluation code changes the timestamp of model.ckpt file. Why's that?

Comment: Thanks, yes. I'm concerned about the training data (stored in the model* files, I assume). Evaluation - `yconv in sess.run(y_conv, feed_dict={x: xtest, keep_prob: 1.0}): ` - seems to update these model* files (at least their timestamps), I wonder why and if the changes affect the training data stored within the files in some way. Ideally, it should just access them in a readonly mode. Thanks for the suggestion about using a different directory, I could try that as well with some intermediate process that copies the trained model over for evaluation (but I'm hoping it works without it).